grafana how to display data from different sources on the same time series with different colours
I have time series data from different sources. Let say several temperature sensors (A, B, C) provide me with outdoor temperature (T) over the time t.
The data per time is like: T(t) from A sensors, then T(t) from B sensor, then T(t) from C sensor.



time t
Temperature T
Sensor id




00:00:01
27.5
A


00:00:02
27.6
A


00:00:03
27.4
B


00:00:04
27.5
B


00:00:05
27.7
B


00:00:06
27.5
C



I want to display temperature over time on my time series plot from all sensors on one plot. Not separate plot for each sensor.
But I want to know which sensor provides the data. The simplest way is to have different colours of dots (or may be background).
So is it possible to changes colour for part of plot based on some meta data (for each point T(t) I knew the sensor id).

How is this different from having actual different plots?

Imaging you have 10-20 or even more sensors, not 3. Some process are better to observe on the same plot, not different.

Sorry, maybe we have some form of misunderstanding. In this exact circumstance I understand your usage of word plot as a line on panel. So this panel has 4 plots. If that is not correct, please explain what you mean.

You are correct, by plot I mean the line of data over time.
On your example imaging that instead of web_servers you have temperature sensors and they provide you with the same data - outside temperature (T). Not simultaneously but one after another, separated by some time delta.
The temperature is displayed as one line - T over time. I want somehow to display which sensor provides data at certain time.

I don't think what you want is possible. Grafana can either treat them as separate time series, and thus graph as separate plots, with respective colours. If only one value is present for each timestamp, I'd imagine this would very close to desired result. Or Grafana can treat them as a single timeseries (effectively ignoring sensor id), but then they all will have same color (and will be indistinguishable).

It would be nice Grafana allows to use some metadata for each point. And according to this metadata you can change background and other properties

You are free to implement this as a plugin.
